# React - infinite scroll for table

Tags: reactjs

I have an infinite scroll located at the bottom of the page, and when scrolling to the end of the table, it will fetch and bring more data. This table contains also a search for each column:
[image]

The issue starts once the user enters a value into one of the search boxs.
That is when I filter the data and return filtered fields, but once I do that, the table has fewer rows, thus, it gets to the bottom of the page and sends a fetch call to get more data and the table is not being filtered anymore. What will be the best practice to deal with this issue?

Thanks

Comment: When user start filtering then you have to set a flag to userInFiltering =true and set scroll to top of the table and in fetching data always check userInFiltering === false

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't provide the best solution for corner cases, what if the user filters a column and wants to scroll to the bottom of the table and gets more data?

Comment: You have to set userInFiltering = false after scroling to top of table, after this user can scroll down for get more data with new filter parameters

Comment: What if after filter table returns only one row? You don't really scroll to the top and again it will trigger the fetch

Comment: God ! you need to check scrollTop and scrollHeight value before start fetching or check a number of records per fetch (25 row per fetch) then decide to start fetching ( same as filtering but you need to start one more fetching if you got less than 25 row after filtering )